# How to disable IE/Edge basic styles?

Tags: javascript, css, html, sass

Is it possible to disable basic select styles from Internet Explorer/Edge?

Example (dropdown):

[image]

Dropdown active:

[image]

The browser always overrides my styles with those ugly black bordered boxes.

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS reset ?

Comment: On form elements CSS support is very limited in most browsers.

Comment: refer this link : https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: unfortunately reset css doesn't affect elements with the select tag

Comment: That's the in-built design you've to live with IE/Edge, it's not customizable. If you want a dropdown list to look different, you've to create your own list elements using e.g. `ul` elements and style them as you want. There are also many libraries for the task.

Comment: @Teemu Ok, thanks for your answer.

Comment: In IE/Edge, a limited set of properties of control elements can be customized by [Microsoft CSS extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Microsoft_extensions). Maybe you can find something from that page.